# Add constraint programmatically to Views

Tags: swift, constraints

Here is my simple code to add constraint:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        contentView.frame.size.width = 250
        contentView.frame.size.height = 100
        contentView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(contentView)

        let userNameLabel = UILabel()
        userNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        userNameLabel.text = "Username:"
        contentView.addSubview(userNameLabel)

        let passwordLabel = UILabel()
        passwordLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        passwordLabel.text = "Password:"
        contentView.addSubview(passwordLabel)

        let usernameTextField = UITextField()
        usernameTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        usernameTextField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
        contentView.addSubview(usernameTextField)

        let passwordTextField = UITextField()
        passwordTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        passwordTextField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
        contentView.addSubview(passwordTextField)

        let submitButton = UIButton()
        submitButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        submitButton.setTitle("Submit", forState: .Normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
        submitButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
        contentView.addSubview(submitButton)

        // For Username
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: userNameLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: userNameLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: usernameTextField, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: usernameTextField, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: userNameLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 3).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: userNameLabel, attribute: .Baseline, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: usernameTextField, attribute: .Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        // For Password
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: userNameLabel, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 15).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 3).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordLabel, attribute: .Baseline, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordTextField, attribute: .Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        // For Button
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: submitButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordLabel, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: submitButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
    }

}
```

But why it look like this, I want the `passWordTextField`'s  Leading is `3` to the Trailing of `passWordLabel`:

[image]

I look at this line and can not find any problems:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 3).active = true
```

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the label and textfield have the same hugging priority. You need to define which one to prioritize. Example:

```
userNameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(251, forAxis: .Horizontal)
passwordLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(251, forAxis: .Horizontal)
```

Comment: It worked. Because I think that UILabel will automatically set it width base on the text inside it. But why the userNameLabel works while the passwordLabel do not work.

Comment: But when I change text on passwordLabel, it looks so bad.

Comment: No, the problem is not that. Please check again.

Comment: Ok, I know what the issue is. Let me update my answer.

Comment: It works but is randomly deciding which one to prioritize as you can tell by your screenshot. Now that the labels are prioritized, it will behave as expected. You can still add an equal width constraint between the labels to make the textviews start at the same x coordinate.

Comment: No, just add two lines from yours, it's enough. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that: this line :

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 3).active = true
```

should be appear before with this line:

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
```

the code for password will look like:

```
 // For Password
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordLabel, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).active = true
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordLabel, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: userNameLabel, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 15).active = true
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordLabel, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 3).active = true
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordTextField, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: passwordLabel, attribute: .Baseline, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: passwordTextField, attribute: .Baseline, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
```

[image]